# How to scrape the website which returns an empty table?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

## The Problem

I am trying to scrape the [website](https://www.turkiye.gov.tr/mersin-yenisehir-belediyesi-arsa-rayic-degeri-sorgulama). However, I can't reach the table content when I post a request from the Postman. I tried Request library to get info. I tried to use cloudscraper library to look like a person. Result HTML's table is empty. How can I solve it?

## Screenshoots

[1 - The Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XzF4.png)
[2 - Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0bzp.png)

## Code

```
import requests

url = "https://www.turkiye.gov.tr/mersin-yenisehir-belediyesi-arsa-rayic-degeri-sorgulama?submit"

payload='btn=Sorgula&caddesokak=&id=&islem=&mahalle=27&token=%7B609B03-5C5357-904654-84788D-227746-F7EEF8-F661BE-1B3F90%7D&yil=2021'
headers = {
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="95", "Chromium";v="95", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
  'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
  'DNT': '1',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Safari/537.36',
  'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
  'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
  'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
  'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
  'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
  'Cookie': 'TURKIYESESSIONID=9a8ab4rjv7oprv5atidcmlo95i; language=tr_TR.UTF-8; TS01ee3a52=015c1cbb6d657270d7a05c71f0c60353ad5d33d8832ac14f33c8078bc783d34e5862d30b42518895fc09263e263aa5d0c8ac69356e191fa7dfed849b6029e59b84d9634c98180a76df4845df847364cfd3771e1e8c; w3p=4090734784.20480.0000'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: What does a "solution" look like?  Wouldn't it be sufficient to check for an empty table?

Comment: I must get content in the table. I will use pandas and I will export the result as Excel.

Comment: Unforutnelly, the website probably relies heavily on JS, and you won't be able to fetch the data using a simple request, you'll need to use Selenium to fetch the content.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that, postman and the request library don't work with javascript and the site you're trying to scrape relies heavily on javascript, I personally check in my browser and if you disable JS in that site it returns a blank page, a workaround is the [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/) library, it has a learning curve but it will be able to scrape any site like that.